# Node.js Mongoose Promise getting lost

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bcrypt

I have a Node.js API with a mongoDB. There is a route that creates a user and needs to hash the password, for this I use the bcryptjs package.

the route looks like this:

```
router.route('/user')

    .post(function(req, res) {
        if(req.body.password === req.body.passwordConfirm) {
            userManager.addUser(req.body)
                .then(function(response) { // waiting for the result of the mongoDB save
                    res.send({data:response});
                });
         } else {
             res.send({err:'passwords do not match'});
         }
     })
```

and userManager.addUSer:

```
this.addUser = function(userobject) {
    bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) { // generate a salt
        if(err !== null) {
            console.log(err);
        } else {
            bcrypt.hash(userobject.password_hash, salt, function(err, hash) { // hash pw
                if(err !== null) {
                    console.log(err);
                else {
                    userobject.password_hash = hash; // store hash in user obj
                    var user = new User(userobject);
                    return user.save().catch(function(err){ // save user in mongoDB
                        console.log(err);
                    });
                }
            });
        }
    });
};
```

I get an error saying: "Cannot read property 'then' of undefined", which tells me that I am not receiving a promise from addUser. I looked and bcryptjs sadly does not use promises, however, mongoose does.
(adding this:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose').Promise = Promise;
```

didn't help)

I tried wrapping the function in a promise with reject and resolve, but that gives this error: "TypeError: Promise resolver undefined is not a function".

How do I get the promise that the save() function of mongoose returns back to the .then() in the post route? I tried adding return in front of the two bcrypt function but that didn't work either..

Any suggestions are welcome!

Comment: You do not return a Promise form your `this.addUser`.

Comment: to be clear, you don't return **anything** from `this.addUser`

Comment: @Jaromanda X yes I see that now, I am new to promises and I think I got lost by the API that does not support promises..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `addUser` function nevers returns the promise to its caller. You're doing a `return` from the `bcrypt.hash` callback function, but that has nothing to do with `addUser`'s return value.

It looks like `addUser` has to use some non-Promise-enabled APIs, so you're stuck with doing `new Promise`, something like this (see the `***` comments):

```
this.addUser = function(userobject) {
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) { // ***
        bcrypt.genSalt(10, function(err, salt) { // generate a salt
            if(err !== null) {
                reject(err);                       // ***
            } else {
                bcrypt.hash(userobject.password_hash, salt, function(err, hash) { // hash pw
                    if(err !== null) {
                        reject(err);               // ***
                    else {
                        userobject.password_hash = hash; // store hash in user obj
                        var user = new User(userobject);
                        resolve(user.save());      // *** save user in mongoDB
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    });
};
```

Also note that I don't have `addUser` just swallowing errors; instead, they're propagated to the caller. The caller should handle them (even if "handling" is just logging).

Answer (score 1):

You do not return a Promise form your `this.addUser`, you have to convert your  callback based `bcrypt` to Promises. You can convert the whole `bcrypt` API to support Promise based functions using e.g. [`promisifyAll`](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/promise.promisifyall.html) of the bluebird library, or do it manually using `new Promise` like this way:

```
this.addUser = function(userobject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          bcrypt.hash(userobject.password_hash, salt, function(err, hash) {
            if (err) {
              reject(err)
            } else {
              resolve(hash)
            }
          })
        }
      });
    })
    .then(hash => {
      userobject.password_hash = hash; // store hash in user obj
      var user = new User(userobject);
      return user.save() // save user in mongoDB
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
       console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Or that way:

```
this.addUser = function(userobject) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      bcrypt.genSalt(10, (err, salt) => {
        if (err) {
          reject(err);
        } else {
          resolve(salt);
        }
      });
    })
    .then(salt => {
      return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        bcrypt.hash(userobject.password_hash, salt, function(err, hash) {
          if (err) {
            reject(err)
          } else {
            resolve(hash)
          }
        })
      })
    })
    .then(hash => {
      userobject.password_hash = hash; // store hash in user obj
      var user = new User(userobject);
      return user.save()  // save user in mongoDB
    })
    .catch(function(err) {
      console.log(err);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

After doing some more digging in the change logs of bcryptjs I found out that they added promises but did not update the documentation.. The genSalt en hash methods will return a promise if the callbacks are omitted. This would translate to:

```
this.addUser = function(userobject) {
    return bcrypt.genSalt(10).then((salt) => {
        return bcrypt.hash(userobject.password, salt).then((hash) => {
            userobject.password_hash = hash;
            var user = new User(userobject);
            return user.save();
        });
    });
};
```